# how to use numpy polyfit to force scatter points linear fit pass through zero?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

```
x=np.asarray([1,2,4,5,7,8,9])
y=np.asarray([2,1,3,6,4,7,9])

m,b=np.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

I have scatter points and try to do a linear fit (y = m*x + b, b = 0) by `numpy polyfit`. Is there a way to force interception b to be 0? Can I also have the variance?

I googled and someone said `np.linalg.lstsq` may work but I don't know how to manipulate it. And I prefer `np.polyfit`. Can it work?

Answer (score 2):

No.  `np.polyfit` doesn't have a method for removing lower order terms.  Here's how you do it with `np.linlg.lstsq`:

```
m = np.linalg.lstsq(x.reshape(-1,1), y)[0][0]
m

0.87916666666666654
```

This is **not** the same as:

```
np.mean(y/x)

0.98520408163265305
```

Comment: what is the [0][0]? can it be only [0] or (0,0)? Can I have the variance or some other parameters?

Comment: No, `np.linalg.lstsq` outputs a list of arrays, so the first `[0]` is list comprehension, and then the next `[0]` is array comprehension.  The residuals would be `[1][0]`.  Check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) to see what else `np.linalg.lstsq` outputs, but much of it isn't useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Linear Algebra maybe overkill here:

```
m = np.mean(y/x)
```

Will do the job fine for an unweighted correlation.

Comment: That's just an average, not a least squared fit.

Comment: The OP didn't specify Lease Squares, but I was wrong in anycase.  i've +1'd your answer.