# Linear fit through point (using weights in NumPy Polynomial.fit())

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

How can a linear fit be forced to exactly pass through a point (specifically, the origin) with [NumPy's Polynomial.fit()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html) function?
I've tried some weights, but I'm unclear on how this works (despite [What are the weight values to use in numpy polyfit and what is the error of the fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19667877/what-are-the-weight-values-to-use-in-numpy-polyfit-and-what-is-the-error-of-the)) so I don't know whether this is the approach to use for an exact solution:

```
""" force fit through point """
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([0, 4, 5, 6])

fit, info = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(
    x, y, 1, full=True, w=[1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]  #!?
)
print(fit)
fitfunc = fit.convert()
print(fitfunc)
print(fitfunc.coef)
print(info)

print(fitfunc(0)) # y-intercept should be zero

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, y, ".")
ax1.plot(x, fitfunc(x), label=str(fitfunc))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46170186/1619432

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use numpy polyfit to force scatter points linear fit pass through zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164012/how-to-use-numpy-polyfit-to-force-scatter-points-linear-fit-pass-through-zero)

Comment: This is a simple matter of using `lstsq` as shown in that answer.

Comment: @Reinderien It does not explain how to find the weights for `fit()`.

Comment: Just.. don't use `fit`. It's not the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly manage this with the `np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit` function, but I'd proceed by using the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function providing your constraint.

```
# 1-D linear function
def regression_line(x0, x1, x):
  return x0 + x*x1

# loss function: root mean squared error
def rmse(y, t):
  return np.sqrt(np.mean(y-t)**2)

# the point you want the line passes through
pivot = [0,0]

# minimize the loss function by taking into account the constraint
best_params = optimize.minimize(
    lambda params: rmse(regression_line(params[0], params[1], x), y),
    x0 = [0,0],
    constraints=({"type":"eq", "fun":lambda params: regression_line(*params, pivot[0])-pivot[1]})
).x
```

Result:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, y, ".")
ax1.plot(x, regression_line(*best_params, x), label="%.2f + %.2f*x"%(best_params[0], best_params[1]))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: constrained linear regression]

Required libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
```

Of course this is a 1-D example, but you can generalize this approach to a multi dimensional linear regression as well.

Answer (score 0):

scikit-learn allows you to do linear regression forcing intercept of zero.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Scikitlearn requires 2-dimensional x and y. You can also do e.g. x.reshape(...)[-1,1]
x = np.expand_dims(np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]),1)
y = np.expand_dims(np.array([0, 4, 5, 6]),1)

#Define model, fit model and predict y from your x
regmodel = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
regmodel.fit(x,y)
y_predict = regmodel.predict(x)

#Print fitted coefficients without intercept 
print(regmodel.coef_)
#Print fitted intercept
print(regmodel.intercept_)

#Plotting
fig, ax= plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, ".", label='Data')
ax.plot(x,y_predict, '-', label='Fitted line')
plt.legend()    
plt.show()
```